How to fix zoom in android using css?
I have code:


h3 {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  font-size:1.2rem;
}

.row-1 {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  font-size:1rem;
}

.row-1 > div {
   display:table;
}

.row-2 {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  font-size:1rem;
}

.row-2 > div {
   display:table;
}
<h3>13. Change to this Privacy Policy:</h3>
<div class="row-1">We have right to change, adjust and modify this Privacy Policy at any time. When changes are applied, we will update you.</div>
<h3>14. Contact us:</h3>
<div class="row-2">
  <div>If you have any questions about our Privacy Policy, please feel free to contact us at:</div></div>



When I open Android.
I click Settings > Display > Font size and style > Font size > I get {max size}.
.row-1 is zoomed, it is not the same. Can you help me? How to fix this bug?


This snippet is working fine for me as Chrome user (whatever is the font-size I set), I suggest you link the font you use , maybe someone would try to dig this out
