How to fix ::marker in safari?
I have code:


.ol-class {
  list-style-type:decimal;
}

.dt {
  display:table;
}
<ol class="ol-class">
  <li><div class="dt">Open app.</div></li>
  <li><div class="dt">Tap on your avatar on bottom right corner.</div></li>
  <li><div class="dt">Tap on icon on upper left corner.</div></li>
</ol>




How to fix this bug in safari but don't remove .dt class. Can you help me?

Why do you want the list items displayed as tables?

I used it because it fixed some bugs for me.

Could display: inline-table perhaps fix those bugs as well? Because that makes the above show the same in Safari, as it does in Chrome.

Perhaps you should find a different solution for the "some bugs"?

I don't think using display: table is a great idea. What was the original problem(s) you were struggling with? ... perhaps we can help with that.

The simple answer is "don't use display: table on .dt". Doing so may have resolved some bugs but it has also introduced others so it isn't a suitable solution. As Brett alluded to above, you should look to resolve your original bugs properly, not with a hacky solution that introduces other bugs.

I got this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78681399/how-to-fix-zoom-in-android-using-css. When I use display:table, it fixed my bug. I can't find the other solution.
